# .Net 6 core: How to inject a configuration to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, configuration, .net-6.0

What I tried to do:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;
public LoginController(IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;
}


private static JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
{
    var key = _config["Jwt:Key"];

    ... Another code
}
```

I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Vcn.png)

appsettings.json:

```
"Jwt": {
    "Key": "WTAuthenticationHIGHsecuredPasswordVVVp1OH7Xzyr",
    "Issuer": "Issuer",
    "Audience": "Audience"
  },
```

Comment: why do you need a static method inside controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error message is too clear:

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
> property 'member'

you should send `IConfiguration` as parameter to static method.

```
private static JwtSecurityToken GetToken(List<Claim> authClaims, IConfiguration config)
{
    var key = config["Jwt:Key"];
}
```

while using:

```
public IActionResult Get(){
    var claims = GetClaims();
    var token = GetToken(claims, _ config)
}
```